# Fatal error attempting to write to COM port using JSSC [EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION]

Tags: serial-port, jssc

Used JSSC to write/read data from a COM serial device. COM was detected but attempting to write or read gives this error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Comment: code: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/801262/Sending-and-receiving-strings-from-COM-port-via-jS

Comment: `com` is the wrong tag

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in JSSC. Several other people noticed it too (e.g. https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/6788). It seems to happen with Java SE 9 on Windows 10, x64.

Unfortunately, it appears that the JSSC project is no longer maintained/dead. However, as of this writing, there are over 150 forks, some of which appear to be active. For example, maybe the following fork might contain what you're looking for: https://github.com/aploese/spsw

In case you want to go with a different library altogether, this question provides a working example using jSerialComm: [How to fix Java rxtxSerial.dll or jSSC-2.7_x86_64.dll Serial Port Error in Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165395/how-to-fix-java-rxtxserial-dll-or-jssc-2-7-x86-64-dll-serial-port-error-in-windo)